# XCode ibtool command looking for non-existing directory

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, command-line-tool, ibtool

I am trying to use the `ibtool` command-line utility. I have opened Terminal in the project directory, where the `.xib` I want to process is, and I wrote the command as stated in Apple's documentation:

```
ibtool --generate-strings-file MainMenu.strings MainMenu_iPhone.xib
```

I have not this `.xib` file localized yet, so it is not in any localized `.lproj` directory. When I run such command, I get this output:

```
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
```

I have no mounted volume for Xcode. Why is `ibtool` looking for that directory?

I am using XCode 4.4.1 and developing an iOS app. Thanks in advance

Comment: So where is Xcode installed and what does `xcode-select -path` show?

Comment: I have just checked. `xcode-select` really shows that path, but I have XCode installed in `/Applications` folder

Comment: On the other hand, this is the first time I've found problems with the active Xcode path and the first time I try to use an Xcode command-line tool at the same time. Does this Xcode active path not affect anything when using Xcode directly?

Comment: No, it will work correctly from within Xcode; `xcode-select` just effects stuff run from the command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, you have to correct `xcode-select` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html)) in order to use `xcrun` correctly:

(from Terminal.app):

```
$ xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Great!very helpful.With me have many apps which relate to Xcode have the message like that.it happen with me when I have many Xcode version, then remove some olds version.

Comment: I was having the error "xcrun: error: active developer path ("/volumes/xcode/xcode.app/contents/developer") does not exist" while installing the macports, although I faced this erro some time before while installing git too, dont remember how I fixed that time. this Solution worked perfectly for me Thanks 13-JAN-2016